# DataTables: get hidden td element & force update stateSave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I have multiple issues in my project with datatables. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table id="dt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Some headline</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-href="http://localhost/linkforid/1">1</td>
            <td>Some information</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
const table = $('#dt').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': [
        {'targets': [0], 'visible': false}
    ],
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: 0
});

$(document).on('click', '#dt tbody tr', function () {
    let td = table.row(this).data()[0];
    //get data-href attribute???
});
```

**So here are my problems**

**First** of all I want to open the link provided in the first `<td>` whenever I click on a row. For this case I tried to use `table.row(this).data()[0]` (keep in mind this `<td>` is hidden!), however this just returns the text (in this case the number/index 1).

How can I access the ***hidden*** `<td>` element and retrieve the `data-href` attribute?

---

**Second problem:** I am using the `stateSave` option and save it to the `localStorage (stateDuration:0)`. Now I noticed, that whenever I make changes to the table (eg. hide/unhide columns). The changes actually never happen because it draws the table information out of the `localStorage`.

How can I force update my table schema everytime I make changes? Is there a way to ignore table columns (visible: true/false) when using `stateSave`?

***Solution for 2nd Problem:***

```
const table = $('#dt').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': [
        {'targets': [0], 'visible': false}
    ],
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: 0,
    stateSaveParams: function (settings, data) {
        data.columns.forEach(function (column) {
            delete column.visible; //exclude what you dont want
        });
    }
});
```

---

Please feel free to also anwers only 1 question. I really struggle with this issue right know and have no possible solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden columns are removed from dom. You could add the `href` value as attribute to the `<tr>` node itself, or go through the API:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dt tbody tr', function () {
  const href = table.cell({ row: 0, column: 0, order: 'original' }).node().getAttribute('data-href')
  console.log(href) //will always output http://localhost/linkforid/1
})
```

You could add `to$()` to `nodes()` and target the `<tr>` node as a jQuery instance. Btw,

```
$('#dt').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
```

would be much faster since the code not have to travel through the dom starting from the very first node, each and every time.

Comment: wow, thank you for your amazing answer and also for improvment. didn't know that would be the better way to go for =)
however - in your example you have `row: 0` which returns the first row no matter what row was clicked. do you know how to get the clicked row instead? thank you very much

Comment: nvm, got it working. I just used `table.row(this).index()` instead of the `0`. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1st problem, try use this instead of accessing subarray of row data.

```
let td = $(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").data("href");
```

2nd problem, use `stateSaveCallback` & `stateLoadCallback` option on DataTable.

```
    stateSaveCallback: function(settings, data) { //force DataTable to save the settings on localStorage everytime it change
         localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
         return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ) )
    }
```

i haven't tried it yet. But, hope it works!

Comment: you can't access hidden td with just javascript/jquery, since they do not exist in the dom - you need to use the `const table = $..DataTable()` variable.

Comment: 2nd one doesnt seem to work either - it keeps using the old values